# SQL Unwanted Cartesian Product

Tags: sql

I've done plenty of joins in SQL before but this one does not want to work - I'm getting a cartesian product and I have no idea why. I have two tables (in this context) - one is for appointments and another for customers. CustomerId is the primary key of the customer table and is the foreign key of the appointment table.

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a query that shows all of the appointments along with the customer's NAME (stored in customer table).

This is my query:

```
    SELECT a.AppointmentId
    ,a.Subject
    ,a.StartDateTime
    ,c.CustomerId
    ,c.FirstName
    ,c.lastname
FROM shared.Appointment a
INNER JOIN shared.Customer c ON a.CustomerId = c.customerid
WHERE a.BusinessCode = 'bp'
    AND StartDateTime > '2013-02-11'
    AND a.CustomerId > 0
GROUP BY c.customerid
    ,a.AppointmentId
    ,a.Subject
    ,a.CustomerId
    ,a.StartDateTime
    ,c.FirstName
    ,c.lastname
ORDER BY a.AppointmentId;
```

The result is a horrific cartesian product, which only occurs once I start adding in the first/last name into the select part.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The query as it stands should return an error - `where and StartDateTime > '2013-02-11'`. Can you paste in the actual query?

Comment: Whoops. My mistake. I had copy/pasted it in but had taken out where clauses that were not relevant to the question - hence why an 'and' was still there :)

Comment: I don't see how this can create a cartesian product - could you rig up a SQLFiddle to reproduce? Are you sure you're not just getting one row per customer/appointment combination? You will get firstname/lastname for each appointment, if that's what you're experiencing.

Comment: Is what you have posted your **exact** query? It sounds very much like you have something like `ON c.CustomerId = c.customerid` or `ON a.CustomerId = a.customerid`. As has already been said, a cartesian product does not seem possible with the SQL you have posted.

Comment: Hence why I am confused. I have just pasted in the EXACT query (as an edit). Not sure what to do :(

Comment: How many records do you have on the Customer table?

Comment: 2383 customers. 8461 appointments

Comment: Do you have a unique index / primary key constraint on CustomerId on the Customer table? If not, can you try running a `select count(distinct CustomerId) from shared.Customer` query against your database?

Comment: @MarkBannister Yup, customerId is the primary key of the customer table. Count(distinct) returns 2383

Comment: Why do you use `group by` if you are not using an aggregate function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was confused by the cartesian product, so was trying everything I could to fix it. (I'm new to SQL) xD

Comment: I have made a copy of your two tables [On SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f505/3) and filled with random data to match the quantities you have said. I am unable to replicate the issue with your query. If you can reproduce the problem somewhere where everyone can see it, it would be easier to solve the problem.

Comment: @GarethD I have also tried to replicate it elsewhere and I have been unable to. Thanks for trying - it seems to be a problem with this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just attempted a similar but much simpler query with other tables on the database and am still getting a cartesian product. I believe there is a problem with the database, not with the query. I'm not sure anyone on stack overflow could possibly solve this issue without seeing the database.

Thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected cartesian product is often due to a simple typo:

Instead of this:

```
from shared.Appointment a 
    join shared.Customer c on a.CustomerId=c.customerid
```

Perhaps you typed this:

```
from shared.Appointment a 
    join shared.Customer c on a.CustomerId=a.customerid
```

A single character will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I triple-checked that. The query above is copy/pasted exactly. :(